# Why this arithmetic calculation is faster than cast nvarchar?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

The following query is faster (1:05):

```
SELECT DATEPART(DW,DATEFROMPARTS(
 FLOOR(20180501/10000)
,FLOOR(20180501-FLOOR(20180501/10000)*10000)/100
,FLOOR(20180501-FLOOR(20180501/100)*100)))
GO 1000
```

Than (1:10):

```
SELECT DATEPART(DW,CAST(CAST(20180501 AS nvarchar) AS DATE))
GO 1000
```

Why?

I have a table with 2 billions of records (roughly) so the difference becomes important. There is far more logic behind hardcoded date. Otherwise, if there exists a better approach, in term of performace, for executing the same logic, feel free to correct me.

The date column is always an integer, and not always have the same format. Two formats are retrieved YYYYMMDD and, YYYYMM. I know, a bit of a mess.

Thanks!

Comment: *Side note* Why not create a new column or a computed column that is of type `Date` ? Using integers (or any other non date type for that matter) to store date's considered bad practice.

Comment: What are you converting them for? Filtering/display/ETL ?

Comment: @Igor Yes it could help, but would it be faster to create a new column on a table of 2 billion of records and still have to apply some logic than apply this logic directly in a query?

Comment: Why cast the literal as varchar? I it should be in varchar already, no? For one value this ins't a big deal... but for millions of rows it is. Finding the week i could see being slow but if you compare execution plans on both queries (on the data, not the sample) that could help

Comment: @IvanStarostin Delete duplicate rows when the first day of the month (YYYYMM01) is monday

Comment: The point that Igor is making is to use the DATE datatype instead of constantly having to convert to a date. This is going to kill your performance and is one of hundreds of arguments for using the proper datatype.

Comment: `Delete duplicate rows when the first day of the month (YYYYMM01) is monday` <= if you wan to speed up the delete create an indexed temporary table (or permanent if this is recurring) with all 1st Mondays of each month across XX years in the same type and format as this source tables "date" column and use that as the filter. That would allow you to take advantage of any index you might have on the existing table's "date" column.

Comment: @scsimon cause cannot cast int directly to date

Comment: You simply need quotes. But it's only a small difference here. `SELECT DATEPART(DW,CAST('20180501' AS DATE))`

Comment: @Igor Yes I got this table indexed by date and customer_id. That sounds pretty good! Thanks! I will test it!

Comment: Glad to you got answer.But your question and answer are totally different .IMO you judgement on slow performance of query is wrong. I created table with 78 lakh record with int col and use both query.Both were performing exactly same.I will use "cast to varchar(20) instead of nvarchar query(second query) because it is very easy to read.

Comment: if you using result of query in where condition then I can't say.Then we have to see complete query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Delete duplicate rows when the first day of the month (YYYYMM01) is monday

If you wan to speed up the delete create a temporary table (*or permanent if this is recurring operation*) with a column of the same data type as your table's "date" column with all 1st Mondays of each month across XX years. Make sure the data is in the same format as you mentioned in your question. Be sure that this column has an index (clustered). Now use this table in your query as the filter without doing any conversions which will allow Sql Server to take advantage of any indexes that exist on the existing table's "date" column.